# Set xpath for php webdriver selenium

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="info">
                <span class="">
                    Firefox ·
                    <span class="test1">test2</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a class="open-tooltip" href="#"><i alt="" class=""></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This structure is in loop how I class (open-tooltip) element how would I get first, second.. class element - class name is same.

Comment: please share your code trials!

Comment: $elements = $cwebdriver->getElements(LocatorStrategy::className, "popover-tooltip");  if(count($elements) > 0) {

  foreach($elements as $key => $element) {

    if($key == 2) {
                                // here i passes same class index 
     $element->click();

     sleep(2);

     



    }


  }

 }

Comment: thanx i have done by this way